# How to reuse variable from SQL SELECT statement in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, database, django-models

I need to take out values from database , based on distance from any given point and then order by distance ascending. Longitude and latitudes are saved in database as float field. Here is my query

```
SELECT
   *,
   @distance : = 6371 * 2 * asin(sqrt(POW(sin(({lat} - radians(address.latitude)) / 2), 2) + cos({lat}) * cos(radians(address.latitude)) * POW(sin(({lon} - radians(address.longitude)) / 2), 2))) 
FROM
   service,
   provider,
   address 
WHERE
   service.provider_id = provider.id 
   AND provider.address_id = address.id 
   AND provider.status = True 
   AND 
   (
      6371 * 2 * asin(sqrt(POW(sin(({lat} - radians(address.latitude)) / 2), 2) + cos({lat}) * cos(radians(address.latitude)) * POW(sin(({lon} - radians(address.longitude)) / 2), 2)))
   )
   < 10 
order by
   @distance
```

I need to reuse the **distance** for condition like **where @distance < 10**
but I'm unable to reuse, it returns empty list. whereas **@distance** in ORDER BY is working fine. How can i reuse variable in where clause ?

Comment: 'How can i reuse variable in where clause ?' you cannot where is executed before select in the the order of operations so the variable does not exist. Please research sql order of operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you do not need @DISTANCE outside the select, here's an approach to try:

```
    SELECT *,
            6371 * 2 * asin(sqrt(POW(sin(({lat} - radians(address.latitude)) / 2), 2) + cos({lat}) * cos(radians(address.latitude)) * POW(sin(({lon} - radians(address.longitude)) / 2), 2))) AS DISTANCE
    FROM    service,
            provider,
            address 
    WHERE
        service.provider_id = provider.id 
        AND provider.address_id = address.id 
        AND provider.status = True 
    HAVING 
        DISTANCE < 10 
    ORDER BY
        DISTANCE
```

Note that a I have given the calculation an alias DISTANCE(see far right of select) and used HAVING rather than WHERE for the reference to the alias.

Comment: @TheImpaler's comments and query using JOIN are absolutely correct - I did not address the issue as it was not related to your question.

Comment: This is returning raw query set , due to which i cant apply querySet methods which are required after that, this makes code complicated and messy, is there any way to do this with query set ? so that i can apply .filter like methods on this result ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not familiar with django-models.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using MySQL variables; they are obsolete in newer versions of MySQL. Also, it's better to use modern syntax join (SQL-92) instead of old joins.

Anyway, I think the following query produces what you want:

```
select *
from (
  SELECT
    *,
    6371 * 2 * asin(sqrt(POW(sin(({lat} - radians(a.latitude)) / 2), 2) 
      + cos({lat}) * cos(radians(a.latitude)) * POW(sin(({lon} 
      - radians(a.longitude)) / 2), 2))) as distance
  FROM service s
  JOIN provider p ON s.provider_id = p.id
  JOIN address a ON p.address_id = a.id
  WHERE p.status = True 
) x
WHERE distance < 10
ORDER BY distance
```